# Percentage in netlogo

Tags: netlogo

I want to write in Netlogo that a certain percentage of the agent's population has this attribute. How do I do that in NetLogo?

So far, in a toy model, I do it manually. i.e: ask n-of 740 households [set composition 1] when in fact I want to say: ask 8% of the households to set composition 1.

Comment: Amanda, if Matteo's answer has resolved your issue please click the little checkmark to the left of his answer to mark this question as closed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two ways. I will call them *ex-ante* and *ex-post*.

### Ex-ante

A frequent approach is to let each agent have a certain **chance** (expressed as the percentage value) of doing something. In this case you will use the `random-float` command in combination with your percentage value, which is the standard way to make things happen in NetLogo according to a certain probability ([see here](https://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/dictionary.html#random-float), or also see just `random` [if you're working with integers](https://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/dictionary.html#random)). It can be used directly within the `create-turtles` block of commands:

```
globals [
 the-percentage
]

turtles-own [
 my-attribute
]

to setup
 clear-all
 set the-percentage 0.083   ; In this example we set the percentage to be 8.3%.

 create-turtles 500 [
  if (random-float 1 < the-percentage) [
   set attribute 1
  ]
 ]
end
```

This means that you will not *always* have the exact number of turtles having that attribute. If you check `count turtles with [attribute = 1]` on multiple iterations, you will see that the number varies. This approach is good if you want to reproduce the probability of something happening (over a population of agents or over time), which is the case for many uses of NetLogo models.

### Ex-post

The *ex-post* approach follows the logic that you more or less expressed: first you create a number of turtles, later you assign to them the attribute. In this case, you simply need to treat the percentage as in any other mathematical expression: multiply it by the total number of turtles to get the relevant turtles:

```
globals [
 the-percentage
]

turtles-own [
 my-attribute
]

to setup
 clear-all
 set the-percentage 0.083

 create-turtles 500
 ask n-of (count turtles * the-percentage) turtles [
  set attribute 1
 ]
end
```

With this approach, you will always have the exact same number of turtles with that attribute. In fact, if you run `count turtles with [attribute = 1]` on multiple iterations you'll see that the result is always 41 (500 * 0.083 = 41.5, in fact if the number passed to `n-of` is fractional, [it will be rounded down](https://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/dictionary.html#n-of)).

Comment: Hi @Matteo, in the second example, netlogo doesn't give me the exact same number. I tried the following line: --------------------------- to create-income 
  let p1 0.3
  let p2 0.5
  let p3 0.2
 ask n-of (p1 * 1000) households [set income 1001 + random 19000]
 ask n-of (p2 * 1000) households [set income 20001 + random 20000]
 ask n-of (p3 * 1000) households [set income 40001 + random 60000]
end ------- and i get 399, 401, 200 respectively.

Comment: @AmandaK By only reading that code (i.e. without being able to try a fully reproducible example), the problem should be that when the `create-income` procedure runs the first `ask n-of`, it takes 300 random agents and asks them to `set income`. Then, when it runs the second `ask n-of`, it takes some 500 random agents and asks them to `set income`. However, these 500 agents are truly random, i.e. among them there can be some of those who were part of the first 300 agents selected by the first `ask n-of`. And the same goes for the third `ask n-of`. This will certainly mess up the numbers.

Comment: @AmandaK You can include something like: `ask n-of (p2 * 1000) (houselds with [income = 0]) [set income 20001 + random 20000]`, and the same for the third `ask n-of`. This way, you make sure to target only those agents who have not been asked to set their income yet. If the last `ask n-of` is always only targeting residual agents, it can even become `ask households with [income = 0] [set income 40001 + random 60000]`.